# Time String Overlapping

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to create a timer and for that I used toLocaleTimeString(). I got the string but the string is overlapping while rendering on the screen. I tried to change the size of the text and margin as well, but it didn't worked.

I tried to change the font-size and margin of the container. I got the time string using the code:

```
function App() {
  let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  let [currTime, getNewTime] = useState(time);

  function getTime() {
    time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    getNewTime(time);
  }

  setInterval(getTime, 1000);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{currTime}</h1>
      <button onClick={getTime}>Get Time</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
 font-size: 100px;
}

.container {
  margin: 60% auto;
}
```

I want to know how can I overcome this string overlapping problem without changing time into 24 hour format.

Comment: is it styling problem?
If so, then show print screen pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the string overlapping issue without changing the time format to 24-hour format, you can try using the CSS property white-space: nowrap; on the h1 element. This will prevent the time string from breaking into multiple lines and overflowing the container.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Add this line to prevent line breaks */
}

.container {
  margin: 60% auto;
}
```